# Stubbing other repository calls in current repository test

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, chai, sinon, stub

I am trying to write test cases for an Node.js backend project
The database is using pg-promise.  I run into issue when trying to stub the repository and it tries to call other repositories.

Here is the repository file **user.js**

```
    async findByRefToken(refToken) {
            return await this.db.oneOrNone(`SELECT id FROM useraccount WHERE username = $1`, refToken);
        }

    

    async createNormal(data) {
        // generate a verify email token
        const verifyToken = await this.generateToken();
        // create unique ref code
        const tokenid = nanoid(Number(env.REF_TOKEN_LENGTH));
        const refToken = await this.generateUniqueRefToken(tokenid);
        // find the referral's id from the ref token
        let referredBy = null;
        if(data.referred) {
            referredBy = await this.findByRefToken(data.referred);
        }
        const meta = {
            dob: data.dob,
            gender: data.gender,
            country: data.country,
            phone: data.phone,
            email_verified: false,
            verify_token: verifyToken,
            ref_token: refToken,
            referred: referredBy ? referredBy.id : null
        };

        const verificationMeta = {
            kyc_verified: false
        };

        const normalUser = {
            id: data.userId,
            first_name: data.firstName.trim(),
            last_name: data.lastName.trim(),
            active: true,
            email: data.email.trim().toLowerCase(),
            username: data.username.trim(),
            role: 'Normal',
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(data.password, Number(env.SALT_ROUNDS)),
            meta: meta,
            verification_meta: verificationMeta
        };
        const newUser = await this.db.one(CREATE_NORMAL_USER, normalUser);

        return {
            id: newUser.id,
            firstName: data.firstName,
            email: data.email,
            verifyToken: verifyToken,
            refToken: refToken,
            referredBy: referredBy
        };
    }
```

I am trying to test the **createNormal** function, but it would also call other repo function like **findByRefToken**  and **await this.db.one(CREATE_NORMAL_USER, normalUser);** Is there anyway to stub them away?

And here is the test written **user.test.js**

```
    const chai = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const expect = chai.expect;
const {faker} = require("@faker-js/faker");
const UserRepository = require("../../repos/user");
describe("UserRepository", function() {
    const stubValue = {
        dob: faker.date.birthdate(),
        gender: faker.name.gender(),
        country: faker.address.country(),
        phone: faker.phone.number(),
        email_verified: false,
        id: faker.datatype.uuid(),
        firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
        lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
        username: faker.name.fullName(),
        password: faker.random.alphaNumeric(5),
        email: faker.internet.email(),
        verifyToken: faker.random.alphaNumeric(12),
        refToken: faker.random.alphaNumeric(12),
        referredBy: faker.random.alphaNumeric(12)
    };
    describe("create", function () {
        it("should add a new user to the db", async function () {
            // const stub = sinon.stub(UserRepository, "createNormal").resolves(stubValue.refToken);
            const userRepository = new UserRepository();
            const user = await userRepository.createNormal(stubValue);
            expect(user.id).to.equal(stubValue.id);
            expect(user.name).to.equal(stubValue.name);
            expect(user.phone).to.equal(stubValue.phone);
            expect(user.id).to.equal(stubValue.id);
            expect(user.verifyToken).to.equal(stubValue.verifyToken);
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you for responding

Answer (score 0):

The method creates and saves a new user in the database. What is left to test if you stub the database calls?

My recommendation would be to not mock; set up the appropriate structures in the database and use them. You can use [`factory-bot`](https://github.com/ratson/factory-bot) to make this simpler.

Note: it's strange that it doesn't return a user.

---

I'd extract making the user from saving the user. I'd also put all the token and referral stuff into their own methods.

```
    async newNormal(data) {
        const verifyToken = await this.generateToken();
        // create unique ref code
        const tokenid = this.generateTokenId();
        const refToken = await this.generateUniqueRefToken(tokenid);
        const referredBy = await this.findByRefToken(data.referred);

        const meta = {
            dob: data.dob,
            gender: data.gender,
            country: data.country,
            phone: data.phone,
            email_verified: false,
            verify_token: verifyToken,
            ref_token: refToken,
            referred: referredBy ? referredBy.id : null
        };

        return {
            id: data.userId,
            first_name: data.firstName.trim(),
            last_name: data.lastName.trim(),
            active: true,
            email: data.email.trim().toLowerCase(),
            username: data.username.trim(),
            role: 'Normal',
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(data.password, Number(env.SALT_ROUNDS)),
            meta: meta,
            verification_meta: {
                kyc_verified: false
            };
        };
    }

    async createNormal(data) {
        const userData = await this.newNormal(data);
        return await this.db.one(CREATE_NORMAL_USER, userData);
    }
```

Now `createNormal` is an integration method. All it does is call `newNormal` and pass the result through to a SQL query. You can test it by mocking `newNormal` and `db.one`.

The important work is happening in `newNormal`, focus testing on that. You can mock `generateToken`, `generateTokenId`, `generateUniqueRefToken` and `findByRefToken`. But, again, this test would be easier and more realistic by just setting up the necessary data.

Comment: thank you for the reply.  It does look a-lot cleaner with your approach.  How would I mock **generateToken**, **generateTokenId**, **generateUniqueRefToken** and **findByRefToken** <br/><br/>
And you are right, it makes no sense to stub  const stub = sinon.stub(UserRepository, "createNormal").resolves(stubValue.refToken); <br/><br/>
I commented out because it wouldn't let me stub.  It threw out error saying createNormal couldnt be found.

Comment: @IdontEvenEven Mock them to return fixed values. Make sure that fixed value shows up on the object returned from newNormal. Sorry, I don't now the specific syntax in Jest (I'm familiar with rspec which is very similar). [Here's the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) FWIW.